# Error using ngx-hm-carousel module when ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I am trying this example https://github.com/ZouYouShun/ngx-hm-carousel. It is working fine but when I run this command:

> ng build --prod

I am getting this error:

ERROR in :

> Unexpected value 'NgxHmCarouselModule in
>   D:/angular-apps/CarouselApp/node_modules/ngx-hm-carousel/lib/ngx-hm-carousel.module.d.ts'
>   imported by the module 'AppModule in
>   D:/angular-apps/CarouselApp/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a
>   @NgModule annotation.

Do u know what is missing?

Using:
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxHmCarouselModule } from 'ngx-hm-carousel';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxHmCarouselModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Share your app.module

Comment: Ok, I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular we have 2 models of compilation

- **JIT - Just-in-Time Compilation** : JIT compilation as the name implies, compiles the application Just-in-Time in the browser at
  runtime.
- **AoT - Ahead-of-Time Compilation :** AoT compilation compiles the application at build time.

By default, with the development build i.e `ng serve` we get JIT compilation. This is how it works. The application code along with the angular compiler is downloaded by the browser. At runtime, when a request is issued to the application, the JIT-compiler in the browser compiles the application code before it is executed.

with the production build i.e `ng build --prod` we get  AoT compilation the angular application is pre-compiled. So this means the browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the application first.
*[`Basic overview of Just In Time (JIT) Vs Ahead Of Time (AOT) Compilation in Angular Applications`](https://medium.com/@jitubutwal144/basic-overview-of-just-in-time-jit-vs-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation-in-angular-applications-d24f04d8f7ca)*

Unfortunately, The library you are using does not support AOT compilation

One workaround is to Tweak your angular.json file set `"aot": false` and  `"buildOptimizer": false`

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,<-----here
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false<----here
            }
```

and Execute `ng build --prod`
if you don't want to modify your angular.json you can go for

```
 ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

or you can modify the build script in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false",
```

and execute `npm run build`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, it saved me! Thanks Vikas :) I will research about AOT because I don´t know what is it :)

Comment: Glad I could help mate,  I have updated my answer as well, Can you make it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this package. This issue was fixed in `ngx-hm-carousel@1.2.1`. See more details at https://alanzouhome.firebaseapp.com/package/NgxHmCarousel.